# Constructing a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Construct a linear map α : $\mathbb{R^4} → \mathbb{R^4}$ whose kernel is spanned by $(1, 0, 0, 1)$ and $(0, 1, 1, 0)$

I'm seeking guidance, how I could construct the required map? The thing is that I am not yet introduced to matrices. The chapter is on vector spaces, and short subchapter basically gives theorem on $\dim(V) = \dim ker(α) + \dim α(V)$. So I need to find a rather simple way how I could do it.

Also, I would appreciate if anybody could expand on how to make sure the transformation's kernel (or image for that matter) contains the required vector(s), again, without using matrices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints & suggestions:

(Note that the solution to the question is not unique. There are many $\alpha$ that satisfy the required conditions.)

Hint #1: Just by observation, we see that the vectors $(1,0,0,-1)^T, (0,1,-1,0)^T$ are orthogonal to the above two (which are orthogonal to each other).

The point is that the vectors $v_1=(1,0,0,1)^T, v_2=(0,1,1,0)^T, v_3=(1,0,0,-1)^T$, $v_4=(0,1,-1,0)^T$  are mutually orthogonal, and are a basis for the space $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Hint #2: To define the linear operator $\alpha$, it is sufficient to define its behaviour on a basis.

So, in order to define $\alpha$, you just need to specify the values of $\alpha(v_k)$, for $k=1,...,4$. In your case, the value must be zero for two specific vectors (which two?) and non-zero for the two other.

Comment: Yeah, I see! It must be zero for those two describing the kernel of the transformation, and non-zero for those you proposed. I had a hunch that I basically needed to find a set of 4 vectors that would be linearly independent. I maybe just underestimated the fact that the solution is not unique. but now I think I get it. Thanks!